# Ionic Splash Screen Spinner not working

Tags: android, xml, ionic-framework

I'm a newbie to mobile application development. Using Ionic I'm creating an Android application and I'm trying to add the loader animation in the splash screen.

I added,

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
```

in my config.xml (I tried to change this both on `myproject/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml` and `myproject/config.xml`).

### config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.reportservices511008" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Services</name>
  <description>
        Services API
  </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

But that doesn't made any change. Am I missing some thing?

Comment: As I understood Lonic  is javascript framework. If i'm right, you should add javascript tags because generaly android developers are not experts in JS.

Comment: Actually, we don't have much to do with JS in the splash screen, because it is handled by wrapper created by Cordova engine probably present in Java.  If I'm right, JS cannot reach there. So, I think it should be handled by some config..

Comment: Please post your config.xml

Comment: @Selva Updated with config.xml

Comment: Just increase the value of SplashScreenDelay to 10000 and test and see the results

Comment: Did you solve this? I may be able to help. Are you using Ionic 1 or 2?

Comment: @Shinobi881 I'm still have that issue. I'm using the Ionic's version 1.7.13 as per `ionic -version` command..